# Spring Batch - Is it possible to write a custom restart in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have been writing a spring batch wherein I have to perform some error-handling.
I know that spring batch has its own way of handling errors and restarts.

However, when the batch fails and restarts again, I want to pass my own values, conditions and parameters (for restart) which need to be followed before starting/executing the first step.

So, is it possible to write such custom restart in spring batch?

UPDATE1:(Providing a better explanation for above question.)

Let's say that the input to my reader in Step 1 is in the following format:

Table with following columns:

```
CompanyName1 -> VehicleId1
CN1 -> VID2
CN1 -> VID3
.
.
CN1 -> VID30
CN2 -> VID1
CN2 -> VID2
.
.
CNn -> VIDn
```

The reader reads this table row by row for a chunk size 1 (so in this case the row retrieved will be CN -> VID ) processes it and writes it to a File object.
This process goes on until all the CN1 type data is written into the File object. When the reader sends the row with company Name of type CN2 , the File object that was created earlier (for company name of type CN1) will be stored in a remote location. Then the process of File Object creation will continue for CN2 until we encounter CN3, in which case CN2 File Object will be sent for storage to a remote location
and the process will continue.

Now, once you understand this, here's a catch.

Let's say the data is currently being  written by the writer for company Name 2 (CN2) and vehicle ID is VID20 (CN2 -> VID20)
in the File object. Then, due to some reason we had to stop the job/the job fails. In that case, the instance that will be saved will be CN2 -> VID20. So, next time when the job runs, it will start from CN2->VID20

As you might have guessed, all the 19 entries before CN2->VID20 which were written in the File Object were deleted permanently when the file Object got destroyed and these entries were never sent through the File to remote location.

So my question here is this:

Is there a way where I can write my custom restart for the batch where I could tell the job to start from CN2->VID1 instead of CN2->VID20?

If you could think of any other way to handle this scenario then such suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: When you restart a failed job instance (using the same parameters), Spring Batch will skip steps that have been successfully executed and resume from where it left off in the last failed chunk-oriented step if any. It is not clear what do you mean by `I want to pass my own values, conditions and parameters`. Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added an explanation for my question. Please do take a look into it. Thank you..!!

Comment: `all the 19 entries before CN2->VID20 which were written in the File Object were deleted permanently when the file Object got destroyed`: why is that? Do you write your file to a persistent disk or in a location that is deleted if the job fails? If you set chunksize=1, this means the file writer will flush data at each record, so if the job fails at item 20, item 19 should have been persisted in the file. Do you write each company data in a separate file? This is very important for the design of your job. I see no need for "custom restart" in your case.

Comment: Data is written to a persistent disk only when all of the companyData is retrieved. For ex.CN1 will be written in a seperate file and will be stored to a persistent storage only when all of it's VIDs are retrieved. Next CN2 will be written in a similar fashion. But until then, this data will be stored in a simple object which will be destroyed if the job stops. So, if we are at CN2->VID20 and the batch stops, all the previous data which was stored in a simple File Object will be lost (since it has not been written to any physical location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to write the data of each company in a separate file, I would use the company name as a job parameter. With this approach:

- Each job will read the data of a single company and write it to a file
- If a job fails, you can restart it and it would resume where it left off (Spring Batch will truncate the file to last known written offset before writing new data). So there is no need for a custom restart "policy".
- No need to set the chunk-size to 1, this is not efficient. You can use a reasonable chunk size with this approach

If the number of companies is small enough, you can run jobs manually. Otherwise, you can always get the distinct values with something like `select distinct(company_name) from yourTable` and write a script/loop to launch batch jobs with different parameters. Bottom line, make each job do one thing and do it well.

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud Ben Hassine for this idea. This is what I had originally planned and this is the most ideal approach to follow. However, the processing time for the generation of these reports will be huge (several hours). Hence, if I trigger multiple jobs of this size, processing of smaller jobs will get affected. Hence, I have to trigger one big job which will create these reports in a loop. Also, I will be getting the company name and VID together through the reader and its not possible to get those through the job triggering the batch.

Comment: Scalability is another argument for the "one job per company" approach. You can run multiple jobs in parallel (in the same JVM using multiple threads or in different JVMs on the same machine or on different machines within a cluster). It is always easier to scale/improve the performance of multiple independent tasks than a single task. If you really want to keep the single job approach, try to use a partitioned step and partition data by company.